# ClassNotFoundException for org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator despite of Import-Package

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I tried running a really simple OSGi "Hello World"-style example with an activator after a longer while again and got a ClassNotFoundException for org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator (see stack trace below).

The environment is basic Equinox (org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2...). All bundles (besides mine) are ACTIVE. I have "org.osgi.framework" in my "Import-Package" declaration in the manifest, and I can see the class in the package dependencies in Eclipse.

Can someone give me a hint on what to try to troubleshoot this?

Kind regards,
André

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 30 more
```

Comment: P.S.: The example is this: http://cumulocity.com/guides/java/hello-world-osgi/

Comment: Is that all the exception text? Also have you declared your Activator class in the Manifest? (though I don't think this is the problem)

Comment: Hey Kerry, thanks for responding. Yes, the activator is in the manifest. Since the full exception is so large, I placed it into pastebin, I hope that's ok: http://pastebin.com/iqPT1fuJ. Cheers, André

Comment: Ohhh dang, I see it now. It's not in my code, it's a missing dependency in Jersey. Ok, now I am one step further.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for answering this myself, but others might have a similar confusing issue. What happened was that there was a third party library (in this case Jersey) requiring a newer version of OSGi that I had included. Hence that library could not find (the right version of) BundleActivator.

Comment: No problem in answering your own question, it sometimes happens that way.

Comment: Do you mean that you added a new version of OSGi in your pom.xml? I am getting a similar error, but I haven't modified the OSGi version, unless there is a hidden dependency lurking in pom.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a line break after the last line of the
manifest