# Dependency needed for JDK 8 but not for JDK 7 (32bit)

Tags: java, maven, java-8, osgi, java-7

So I have this maven project that compiles successfully with a 32bit JDK 7, but when I try to compile it with a 32bit JDK 8, it throws the error in a file X.java

```
class file for org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator not found
```

However, the file contains no direct import of this package, hence I assume it must be used internally somewhere by one of the imports.

If I add the osgi framework's pom dependency the project compiles successfully with JDK 8.

Can anyone help me understand why such a behaviour is observed here i.e why does it work with JDK 7 without the osgi framework jar?

Comment: can you attach the full pom.xml?

Comment: That's a negative, office policies :(

Comment: which osgi version are you using?

Comment: osgi.core 4.3 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.core/4.3.0

Comment: @VasuMistry Then recreate the problem in a new pom.xml not related to your product.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32179689/916225 might help